# Curly Brace Expected Error in C# Unity 2D Code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I've tried the following C# code for unity, and I've gotten a `} expected [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS1513)` error on the curly brace I've marked, and on the last curly brace I've got a `Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS1022)` error on it, that leaves when I delete it, but it should end the Monobehavior body.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }
    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { // error here
    public static float ScrollWheel { get { return Input.mouseScrollDelta.y / 10; } }
    
    }

} // and also here
```

Comment: you can't create property inside a method, move your property outside your method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a property inside a method caused this problem. If your goal was to get the mouse scroll data in every frame (which is an optimization issue for another time), you may do it like so:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    void Start()
    {

    }
    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { 
       //call the method here
       ScrollWheel();
    
    }

     public static float ScrollWheel ();
     {  
        return Input.mouseScrollDelta.y / 10; 
     }
}
```

I created a method instead of a property like above, but this should work similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, you've included a property inside your method. But, be aware that you CAN include [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) within other members.

If your intention is to simply get that value, you could structure your code like this:

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float ScrollWheel => Input.mouseScrollDelta.y / 10;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start ( )
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ( )
    {
    }
}
```

I've used a [Lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) expression for the ScrollWheel value.